# How to replace text in a text file which has been written previously

Tags: python

I have a file which is as follows

```
project1:
analyzeFile
c1
class1
project1:
analyzeFile
c1
class1
project1:
analyzeFile
c1
class1
project1:
analyzeFile
c1
class1
project1:
analyzeFile
c1
class1
```

And the replaced text should be

```
project1:
abcd
xyz
sunny
project1:
analyze
rty
salman
project1:
analyzeFile1
c2
class2
```

That is only inside parameters should change. The operation is same file in (.txt) format

My code is

```
se =  "C:\\Users\\ishaan_sathe\\Desktop\\{}.txt".format(tt)
writer1 = open(se , 'a+')
for lines in writer1:
    print lines
    for za in checked_list:
        if ':' in lines :
            nameqw = lines.partition(":")
            nameqw  = nameqw[0]
            print nameqw[0]
            if tt == nameqw:
                line1 = writer1.next()
                print line1 , "line10000000000"
                path = line1.replace(line1 , str(za))
                writer1.write(path)
                print path , "hey"
```

How to to do this I am new to python

Comment: In your replaced text, some of the same strings like `analyzeFile` are replaced with different strings (`abcd`, `analyze`, `analyzeFile1`). So the question is where are these replacement strings coming from, and according to what rule should the original ones be replaced?

Comment: I have a list for the strings comming from other checkbox that is stored by me

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at `str.replace()`

> string.replace(s, old, new[, maxreplace])
>
> Return a copy of string s with all occurrences of substring old replaced by new. If the optional argument maxreplace is given, the first maxreplace occurrences are replaced.

Here you should read the file into memory, and call `.replace("analyzeFile", "abcd")`
(The first one).

Hope this helps

Comment: I know this but what will be written in file is not not known to me . I just have to replace the first part with the other.Means I do not know if "AnalyzeFile " will there or no

Comment: Why do you not know what is in the file? You gave the file in your question!?

Comment: str.replace will be fine if the first argument is not there.

Comment: I just gave it for understanding purpose I am writing to a file with the help of a GUI checkbox so I dont know what will be selected in the checkbox

Comment: You cannot replace strings if you don't know what they are. Well, if you just deleted it and wrote a new one, that would be ruining the input

Comment: I'm sorry but I do not understand. Could you come back when you can make the question a little clearer?

Comment: And take a look at the comments on your post - especially @dsalaj 's

Answer (score 0):

Better don't write and read to a file at the same time (very large files are the exception, to save memory). You risk overwriting text that has not been read yet when the replacement string is not the same length. It is very tricky.

Instead, read everything in memory first and put all lines in, for example, a list (one large string is also possible). Then modify the lines and finally overwrite the file with the new lines.

Something like this:

```
se =  "C:\\Users\\ishaan_sathe\\Desktop\\{}.txt".format(tt)

reader = open(se , 'r+')
list_of_lines = reader.read().splitlines()
for line_number, line in enumerate(list_of_lines):
    for za in checked_list:
        if ':' in line:
            nameqw = line.partition(":")
            nameqw  = nameqw[0]
            if tt == nameqw:
                list_of_lines[line_number + 1] = str(za)
reader.close()

writer = open(se, 'w+')
for line in list_of_lines:
    writer.write(line)
writer.close()
```